# How I extract data from two different classes(td.fonce and td.clair):

Tags: html, scrapy

Html code is below, I can't extract data because of different classes;
Only td.fonce class data extracted to file but not td.clair.

```js
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "vxvault"
    start_urls = [
        'http://vxvault.net/ViriList.php?s=0&m=40',
    ]
    
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for fonce in response.css('td.fonce'):
            if fonce is not None:    
                yield {
                   'URL': fonce.css('a::text').extract_first(),
                   #'MD5': fonce.css('a::text')[2].extract(),
                   #'IP': fonce.css('a::text')[3].extract(),
                  }
        for clair in response.css('td.clair'):
            if clair is not None:
                yield {
                        'URL': clair.css('a::text').extract(),
                        }
```

Comment: <tr>
<td class="fonce"><a href="ViriFiche.php?ID=39750">12-24</a></td>
<td class="fonce"><a href="files/A16D9C8D6385E0CF8D01B3FA97EFE439.zip">[D]</a> <a href="ViriFiche.php?ID=39750">draven.ru/stub.exe</a></td>
<td class="fonce"><a href="ViriList.php?MD5=A16D9C8D6385E0CF8D01B3FA97EFE439">A16D9C8D6385E0CF8D01B3FA97EFE439</a></td>
<td class="fonce"><a href="ViriList.php?IP=159.89.222.47">159.89.222.47</a>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="fonce"><a href="http://pedump.me/a16d9c8d6385e0cf8d01b3fa97efe439">PED</a> 
<a href="http://urlquery.net/search?q=159.89.222.47">UQ</a>
</td>
</tr>

Comment: for me it looks that you should have data, can you share the logs you get? on an external file please.

Comment: Example Data:
[
{"URL": "12-26"},
{"URL": "[D]"},
{"URL": "87F71F1773842113AE06EE38E95FFBD0"},
{"URL": "185.118.166.205"},
{"URL": "PED"},
{"URL": "12-26"},
{"URL": "[D]"},
{"URL": "0A0AE5D804271F56C1FA5E1E695CC514"},
{"URL": "103.83.81.144"},
{"URL": "PED"},
{"URL": "12-26"},
{"URL": "[D]"},
{"URL": "0A0AE5D804271F56C1FA5E1E695CC514"},
{"URL": "103.57.220.159"},
{"URL": "PED"},
{"URL": "12-24"},
{"URL": "[D]"},
{"URL": "55B2BB86AD725D3FA77E8A680E60A3BE"},
{"URL": "185.43.223.114"},
{"URL": "PED"}
]

Comment: So I see you are getting data. What’s the problem? The formatting?